# Loop is not printing in Right type

Tags: php, html, mysql

Whenever I use table tag in the loop it works perfectly but when I use div tag I does not work. Basically, I want to make things in center so that's why I am using div tag. 
Logic Tier:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

public function Books_Display()
{
    $connect=new clsdatabase();
    $link=$connect->Connect_Database();
    $dis_qry="select * from tbbook";
    $dis_result=mysqli_query($link,$dis_qry) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $output[]="<div id='cap'>";
  //  $output[]='<table>';
    $i=1;
    while($dis_row=mysqli_fetch_row($dis_result))
    {
        $i++;
        if($i==2)
        {
            $output[]='<div>';
            $i=0;
        }
        $output[]='<span>';
        $output[]="<img src=$dis_row[5] width=50 />";
        $output[]='</span>';
        $output[]='<span>';
        $output[]="Title:<a href=cart.php?bid=$dis_row[0]>$dis_row[1]</a><br>";
        $output[]="Author:$dis_row[2]<br>";
        $output[]="Publisher:$dis_row[3]<br>";
        $output[]="Price:$dis_row[4]<br>";
        $output[]="<a href=cart.php?bid=$dis_row[0]&action=Add>Add To Cart</a><br>";
        $output[]='</span>';
        if($i==1)
        {
            $output[]='</div>';
        }
    }

}
```

I need 1 row = 2 col
2 row= 2 col
long as data ......
there is two one what output is coming and what I want.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXfa9.png)

[This is what i need and in future, i need id to use in css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPSqD.png)

Comment: in 2nd iteration, u need to close div and open a new div?? ?

Comment: `$output[]='<div>';` this will add in ist iteration and `$output[]='</div>'; this will add in 2nd. or maybe u just need to start from 0 here `$i=0;`

Comment: still, your question is not clear, do you want to use `<div id='cap'>` for ist iteration and `<div>` for next one?

Comment: <div id='cap'> is the main block and I will use it in CSS to make the content in the center. But when I use table it creates 2 blocks in a row like 1date + 2data then breakline and 3data+4data from Database. in div it creates one block only for one data then it goes for the next one. In one row one Data in div but in the table the output is One Row Two data fetched.

Comment: but why u need `$output[]='<div>';` ? can u please show the expected output? in html example?

Comment: can u tell me how to share the image? Sorry, I am new here.

Comment: edit your question and press CTRL+G

Comment: $output[]='<div>'; is when in a first row 2 row of data will enter then it will go for next div block i have use while + $i to do that.

Comment: please share expected output

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: `#cap{width:100%}` use this for main div and add a class for inner div like `.innerDiv{width:50%}` and add it in inner div like `<div class="innerDiv">`

Comment: or if you are using bootstrap in your project, then it will be more easy.. are u using?

Comment: no i am not using bootstrap

Comment: then `#cap{width:100%} use this for main div and add a class for inner div like .innerDiv{width:50%} and add it in inner div like <div class="innerDiv">` this is best solution

Comment: not working let me give you my another worked with table and it is printring the content in correct rows

Comment: - while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $i++;
            if($i==2)
            {
                $output[]='<tr>';
                $i=0;
            } $output[]='<td>';
            $output[]="<img src=$row[bimg] width=50 />";
            $output[]='</td>';
            $output[]='<td>';

Comment: $output[]="<a href=detail.php?bid=$row[bid]>$row[btitle]</a><br/>";
            $output[]="Author:$row[baur]<br>";
            $output[]="Publisher:$row[bpub]<br>";
            $output[]="Price:$row[bprice]<br>";
            $output[]="<a href=cart.php?bid=$row[bid]&action=Add>Add to Cart</a><br>";
            $output[]='</td>';
            if($i==1)
            {
                $output[]='</tr>';
            }

Comment: this is working like second image in the question ... and i want that same in div tags

Comment: i suggest you to make it simple html before converting into PHP loop, create simple html with css styling then convert into while loop

Comment: i can't because designed is in database and i have fetch and display it on the index page.

Comment: let me try with another method . I will do this in single page. right now i am doing in three tier Database, Bussiness logic, presentation tier.

Comment: You can use Modulus to operate the if condition to the correct way without reset that counter ;) http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.arithmetic.php#70424